# configure says I don't have lib, but aptitude says I do

Tags: package-management, aptitude, libgcrypt

I've just run a configure script which alerts me:

```
checking for gcry_control in -lgcrypt... no
configure: error: libgcrypt not found. Install libgcrypt or use --disable-libgcrypt. Have a nice day.
```

But when I run `aptitude search libgcrypt`, I find:

```
v   libgcrypt-dev                   -                                           
i   libgcrypt11                     - LGPL Crypto library - runtime library     
p   libgcrypt11-dbg                 - LGPL Crypto library - debugger files      
i A libgcrypt11-dev                 - LGPL Crypto library - development files   
p   libgcrypt11-doc                 - LGPL Crypto library - documentation
```

Am I in error? If I don't have the lib installed correctly, how should I rectify this matter? When I try `aptitude install libgcrypt-dev`, I'm told `No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.`

Comment: what If we move with apt-get ?

Comment: Output: `Note, selecting 'libgcrypt11-dev' instead of 'libgcrypt-dev' libgcrypt11-dev is already the newest version.` No change.